# How to move the XML file after I take all data from it. "Filesystem Functions"

Tags: php, file, loops

I'm using glob to get all the files in the folder using foreach to loop though them

I want to move each file before the loop move to the second file, so I don't get the same data again.

is that possible ?

php  code

get files location

```
$files = glob('1232.{xml}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach ($files as $file => $value) {
```

loading the file to get the values from it

```
$xml   =  simplexml_load_file("$value");
```

loop through the data or tree to get the values

```
 foreach ($xml->Dt->En->Ent->Ms->Mvt->T->TC as $value2){
foreach ($value2->Ss->Sp as  $value1){

}}}
```

as I explained is there a way to know when the file reach to the end and move it to another directory before the loop goes to the  next file!

Comment: `}}/*move the file here with php*/}` ;)

Comment: I know, but how I do that.  I know how to move a file, but I want to do this action  at the end of the file, so the file doesn't load again later

Comment: `so I don't get the same data again` is wrong, because you GLOB and fetch the result into a array. In this array each entry is unique, so you dont get hte same file twice iterated. if you want to prevent collectiing the same data  (from diffrent xml) you have to do it in a other way

Comment: `}}  copy('old/path/file.xml','new/path/file.xml'); }` thats it

Comment: JustOnUnderMillions,  I think  I got you point. I will  move them after certain amount of time, before the new files come.  Thank you ^^

Comment: ------- :-)  ---------------

Comment: ha ha ha you mean is to put  the code at the end of the loop .  ok ok   Thank you  I got it know.. Thanks man